# Automatically add people in recipients list to my mail in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

Is it possible in Gmail that because I usually send forward mails to four constant people, that now when I press forward it automatically puts them in the to field? 
Or when I send a mail to one - it adds the others automatically.

Sounds weird I know.

Answer (score 4):

Create a contact group and add the people that you use as a set. Then when you compose mail, start typing the name of the group and it will allow you to send email to the entire group without remembering everybody in the set.

Answer (score 1):

Other than [creating a contact group](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=30970) (which is the ideal solution for your case as I see it), in case you've missed it, you can also just use [**Don't forget Bob**](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/04/dont-forget-bob-and-got-wrong-bob.html).

<sup>Very cool feature (though I've never really needed or used it), even while a [lot of people](http://www.google.com/search?q=gmail%20%22also%20include%22) seem to [hate it for the simple reason they don't get it](http://thepragmaticmarketer.wordpress.com/2011/05/07/googles-new-also-include-field-what-were-they-thinking/). I'd bet none of those dudes would rant about [Got the wrong Bob](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/10/new-in-labs-got-wrong-bob.html).</sup>

What it does is it automatically **suggests** you to include people you e-mail often. It's automatic:

[image: Don't forget Bob]